# Does Polkadot expose nomination pool extrinsics via XCM?

Tags: parachain, xcm, staking

Is it possible to control a nomination pool via `XCM` from a `Parachain` and is there any related documentation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific instructions for the nomination pools in XCM protocol.
But you can use `Transact` instruction of the protocol to execute arbitrary call/s on a remote chain.

It should be possible to execute nomination pool call over XCM from the parachains. The execution should be paid (check the barriers).

- barriers which you should take into account - https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/7c1dc9429245d705ffb188b16ad5339c6de281c1/runtime/polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L158
- calls filter which includes nomination pools - https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/7c1dc9429245d705ffb188b16ad5339c6de281c1/runtime/polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L286
- docs - https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-format#transact
- instruction -https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/e05b78689d3fb0deb555ede9f0f0e191cc5e18b5/xcm/src/v3/mod.rs#L480